# Where do Kohonen and counterpropagation networks fall in the scheme of neural network architectures?

Tags: neural-network

This [site](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/8-neural-network-architectures-machine-learning-researchers-need-learn.html) sums up various neural network architectures, which fall into broader categories listed below:

- feed-forward networks (don't form cycles)
- recurrent networks (have directed cycles)
- symmetrically connected networks

Then, specific types of neural networks are listed:

- perceptron
- convolutional
- recurrent
- long/short term memory
- Hopfield
- Boltzmann machine
- deep belief
- autoencoder

I have not found where Kohonen (now more commonly referred to as self-organizing maps) and counterpropagation networks (multi-layer Kohonen networks) fit into this scheme in this or other literature.  They used to be more commonly used in the 1980s and 1990s but I am not sure where they fall in the categorization of neural nets.